# Moose Attribute Not Defined in Builder Method

Tags: perl, class, oop, package, moose

I'm using Moose to create an object but the builder method '_initialize_log' is not able to retrieve the value of the name attribute.

Is there a way for me to run the method only after that attribute has been set?

**EFT.pm**

```
package EFT;
use Moose;

# Attributes
has name => (
    is       => "ro",
    isa      => "Str",
    required => 1
);

has log => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'Str',
    builder => '_initialize_log'
);

sub _initialize_log
{
    $self->{'log'} = "****\n";
    $self->{'log'} .= $self->{'name'} . "\n";
    $self->{'log'} .= `date`;
    $self->{'log'} .= "****\n";
}
```

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use EFT;

# Constants
use constant NAME => 'Test Script';

# Create script object
my $script = EFT->new(name => NAME);

print $script->{'log'};
```

**Output**

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at EFT.pm line 46.
****

Thu Mar  3 12:54:31 EST 2016
****
```

Comment: See the section on laziness in [Moose::Manual::Attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Attributes#Laziness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is still being constructed! Delay your attribute's initialization until after it's constructed. The following delays its initialization until it's used:

```
lazy => 1
```

You could also use a [`BUILD`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod#BUILD) method instead.

```
sub BUILD {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->_initialize_log();
}
```

---

Note that you had three bugs in `_initialize_log`:

```
sub _initialize_log
{
    my $self = shift;              # <-- Won't even compile without this!
    my $log = "****\n";
    $log .= $self->name . "\n";    # <-- Removed reliance on Moose internals
    $log .= `date`;
    $log .= "****\n";
    return $log;                   # <-- The value is to be returned.
}
```

To call it from `BUILD` instead of as a builder, you'll need to change it as follows:

```
sub _initialize_log
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $log = "****\n";
    $log .= $self->name . "\n";
    $log .= `date`;
    $log .= "****\n";
    $self->log($log);              # <--
}
```

Comment: The return value of the builder method is the value that the attribute receives. So shouldn't the builder `return $log` instead setting the attribute?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, I suggested *alternatives* to using a `builder` attribute.

Comment: I was referring to your correction of `_initialize_log`.